# Are $[0, 1)$ and $[0, 1]$ homeomorphic subspaces of the Sorgenfrey line?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness, sorgenfrey-line

My argument is that $\{1\}$ is a connected clopen subspace of $[0, 1]$ while the only connected subspaces of $[0, 1)$ are singular sets, which are not open in $[0, 1)$, so the spaces must not be homeomorphic. Is this reasoning correct?

Is there another argument that does not need require to test connectedness?

Thank you!

Comment: Nitpick: "clopen subspace" doesn't make sense, since "clopen" is a property of sets in a topological space, not topological spaces themselves. The correct phrasing is that $\{1\}$ is a clopen set which induces a connected subspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but you can just say that $[0,1]$ has a clopen singleton (which is $\{1\}$), whereas $[0,1)$ has none.